# How to get the text of a button in a unified event listener?

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling

I have a simple GUI built with netbeans, and array of four buttons which open corresponding pdfs.  I have an action listener, which listens to all four buttons, as follows:

```
private void creditMemoButActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();

   String buttonText = this.getText(); //obviously, this is the problem.

   File pdf = new File("data/"+buttonText+".pdf");
   dt.open(pdf);
}
```

The problem is the commented line.  Obviously, that function doesn't exist, but it illustrates the functionality I don't know how to achieve, simply, in a unified event listener.  Suprisingly, this wasn't easily googlable, at least for me, a novice.

How do I get the text of the button which triggered the action event?

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate.  What is proper SO etiquette in this situation?  Delete the question?  Or answer it myself in 2 days?  Something else?

Comment: I think a moderator will close/lock this thread. I suppose you could also delete if the other link provided the answer you were looking for.

Comment: `JButton button = (JButton)evt.getSource();`. Then you can get its text. [EventObject.getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29).